# Java - is it possible to verify a particular "hardcoded" self-signed certificate by fingerprint, and ignore hostname matches?

Tags: java, ssl, verification, hostname, self-signed

This is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368612/java-asymmetric-encryption-of-traffic-with-pre-shared-public-keys-and-without) (decided to make it separate just in case someone in the future will be looking into similar problem)

Basically, the set up is applet and servlet communicating.

Servlet's cert is self-signed and hardcoded into the applet.

Now, let's say I go the "make truststore in memory, import the hardcoded cert into it" route.

**problem: servlet's IP/hostname are subject to change without warning**

How would one go about making it so that the applet doesn't verify hostname for this particular cert, but still checks other things, such as fingerprint and such?

Additional considerations:

- I'd rather avoid having my applet loose the ability to verify
  hostnames for other certificates.
- I'd also like to avoid any browser popups and pleads for user input
  when dealing with the "hardcoded" cert (We put it there ourselves, of
  course we trust it ^_^)

Thank you very much for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hostname checking only happens over HTTPS. If you're using SSL directly, you don't have the problem.